# Simple VBA Select Query

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, vba

I have a form on MS Access with a button in it, and when I press that button I want to run a SELECT query `"SELECT * FROM City"`.

All the questions on here are very complicated, I just want a simple few lines of code to do that.

Comment: What have you got so far ?

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share issues with a *specific* problem after trying to solve it on their own. If, after **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)**, you have a *specific* problem, please [edit] your post to share [examples of your code](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and some background info about your project. Some good reading to get you started: "[ask]" as well as tips **[here](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and **[here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
 sSQL = "SELECT Variable FROM GroupTable " 
 Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
 On Error GoTo resultsetError 
 dbValue = rs!Variable
 MsgBox dbValue, vbOKOnly, "RS VALUE"
resultsetError:
 MsgBox "Error Retrieving value from database",VbOkOnly,"Database Error"
```